# char poly of 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find characteristic  polinomial  of 3x3 matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}11 & -4 & -5 \\ 21 & -8 & -11 \\ 3 & -1 &0  \end{pmatrix} $$

---

was able to find it with the help of computer

[image]

If it were in a test, it feels like the way I am doing (expanding along first row and a page of algebra ) it would take too long or do some silly algebra mistake that would get the wrong aswer. (No calculators on exam).

*I am wondering if there is a more efficient way by hand*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My students seemed to like this: for a 2 by 2 matrix, let $\sigma_1$ be the trace of it, and $\sigma_2$ the determinant. Then the characteristic polynomial is $$ \lambda^2 - \sigma_1 \lambda + \sigma_2. $$

For a 3 by 3 matrix, let $\sigma_1$ be the trace of it, and $\sigma_2$ the sum of the determinants of the "principal" 2 by 2 minors , and $\sigma_3$ the determinant. Then
$$  \lambda^3 - \sigma_1 \lambda^2 + \sigma_2 \lambda - \sigma_3. $$

For you,
$$  \sigma_2 =
\left| 
\begin{array}{rr}
-8 & -11 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right|  +
\left| 
\begin{array}{rr}
11 & -5 \\
3 & 0
\end{array}
\right|  +
\left| 
\begin{array}{rr}
11 & -4 \\
21 & -8
\end{array}
\right|  
$$
so that
$$ \sigma_2 = -11 + 15 -4 = 0  $$

```
A little computer confirmation:


? 
? n = [ a11, a12, a13; a21, a22, a23; a31, a32, a33 ]
%3 = 
[a11 a12 a13]

[a21 a22 a23]

[a31 a32 a33]

? q = charpoly(n)
%4 = x^3 + (-a11 + (-a22 - a33))*x^2 + ((a22 + a33)*a11 + (-a21*a12 + (a33*a22 + (-a31*a13 - a32*a23))))*x + ((-a33*a22 + a32*a23)*a11 + ((a33*a21 - a31*a23)*a12 + (-a32*a13*a21 + a31*a13*a22)))
? n2 = polcoeff(q,2,x)
%5 = -a11 + (-a22 - a33)
? 
? n1 = polcoeff(q,1,x)
%6 = (a22 + a33)*a11 + (-a21*a12 + (a33*a22 + (-a31*a13 - a32*a23)))
? 
? n0 = polcoeff(q,0,x)
%7 = (-a33*a22 + a32*a23)*a11 + ((a33*a21 - a31*a23)*a12 + (-a32*a13*a21 + a31*a13*a22))
? 
? n0 + matdet(n)
%8 = 0
?
```